# Kali crash while performing apt upgrade

Tags: kali-linux

I'm having some issues.
I'm trying to install a persistence kali linux on my extended hdd.
To do this I followed the following guide:
https://devanswers.co/guide-kali-linux-2018-live-usb-persistence-windows/

After doin all the steps, my persistence kali is up and running perfectly.

Since I mainly want to test hashcat with my GTX 1060 I wanted to install the latest nvidea drivers. To do that, I followed the following guide:
https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/install-nvidia-drivers-on-kali-linux/

Unfortunately i'm already stuck at command 1, which is

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt -y full-upgrade -y && sudo reboot
```

My Kali appears to crash (the computer simply shuts down) while performing the apt upgrade command.
I have no idea how to tackle this problem. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: What's step 1 in your book? The referenced guide has no numbered sections

Comment: kali@kali:~$ sudo apt update && sudo apt -y full-upgrade -y && sudo reboot

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is your extended hard drive. 
I haven't been able to ever get Nvidia drivers to load on live persistent. I think it's related to Kernel and being able to turn off modules related to Xorg/Nouveau. You could install Kali to a USB drive, it would run slow but you could then install the corrected OpenCL drivers. I"m gotten Kali and AMD cards to Hashcat and super fast compared to CPU.

OR

https://askubuntu.com/questions/880367/updating-nvidia-drivers-on-casper-rw-partitioned-usb-prevents-boot [LINK](https://askubuntu.com/questions/880367/updating-nvidia-drivers-on-casper-rw-partitioned-usb-prevents-boot)

Comment: Damn that sucks. It's a LaCie Porsche Design P'9220 1 TB USB 3.0 Portable External Hard Drive 
The speed is an extreme difference....
Gaat de snelheid van hashcat ook niet beperkt zijn bij het gebruik van een USB?

Comment: USB will not slow down Hashcat. Install Kali to the external USB drive and make sure to select that drive as BOOT OS. Once you finish install just reboot and select the USB drive to start Kali. Happy Hashcating